# Can I query GraphQL inside Google Map component?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm playing around with Gatsby/Contentful and Google Maps.

I've created this component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from 'react-google-maps'

const Map = (props) => {

    return (

        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={12}
            defaultCenter={{
                lat: 34.0522,
                lng: 118.2437
            }}
            >

            <Marker
                onMouseOver={() => {
                    setInfoWindow(true)
                }}
                onClick={() => props.setmodal(true)}
                position={{
                    lat: 34.0522,
                    lng: 118.2437
                }}
            />

        </GoogleMap>
    )
}

export default Map;
```

The map is showing and everything works fine. I've tried to access my Contentful data using this approach, but getting an error that allContentfulLocations are undefined. How can I query my Contentful data inside Google Maps?

Here was my approach which is failing.

```
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from 'react-google-maps'
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export const query = graphql`
{
    allContentfulLocations {
      nodes {
        id
        name
        location {
          lat
          lon
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

const Map = ({props, data}) => {

      const {
              allContentfulLocations: { nodes: locations },
            } = data

    const [infoWindow, setInfoWindow] = useState(false)

    return (

        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={12}
            defaultCenter={{
                lat: location.location.lat
                lng: location.location.lon
            }}
            >

            {locations.map(location => {
                return (
            <Marker
                onMouseOver={() => {
                    setInfoWindow(true)
                }}
                onClick={() => props.setmodal(true)}
                position={{
                    lat: 34.0522,
                    lng: 118.2437
                }}
                />
                )
              })}

        </GoogleMap>
    )
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: gatsby is for static content, not live graphql server, can't be queried form runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, Marker, InfoWindow } from 'react-google-maps'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"


const Map = (props) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
{
    allContentfulLocations {
      nodes {
        id
        name
        location {
          lat
          lon
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)
      const {
              allContentfulLocations: { nodes: locations },
            } = data

    const [infoWindow, setInfoWindow] = useState(false)

    return (

        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={12}
            defaultCenter={{
                lat: location.location.lat
                lng: location.location.lon
            }}
            >

            {locations.map(({location}) => {
                console.log(location);
                return (
            <Marker
                onMouseOver={() => {
                    setInfoWindow(true)
                }}
                onClick={() => props.setmodal(true)}
                position={{
                    lat: 34.0522,
                    lng: 118.2437
                }}
                />
                )
              })}

        </GoogleMap>
    )
}

export default Map;
```

If your component (`Map`) is not a page, you won't be able to use page queries and therefore you will be forced to use a [static query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/)

Notice the destructuring in the `map` loop:

```
locations.map(({location}) =>
```

In the way you were using the loop, `location` was the iterable variable, not the `location` object itself. You should access to `location.location` in your approach, you're avoiding that repetition, using a destructuring in the same declaration on the iterable object as I provided. I've also added a `console.log()` for debugging purposes, take a look at what's inside in both approaches.

In addition, if you look at your code:

```
const Map = ({props, data}) => {
```

You are destructuring `props` as `props` itself so. I've removed that destructuring and I've added it to:

```
  const {
          allContentfulLocations: { nodes: locations },
        } = props.data
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'allContentfulLocations' of undefined

Comment: Super strange as always :D It should work with your approach.. but oh well..

Comment: Your code is breaking somewhere else. I've seen something weird in `const Map = (props) =>`. You were destructuring `props` as `props`, I've removed it and added the destructuring in `props.data`.

Comment: I've tried your approaches, they make all sense but I'm still getting the same error message. Perhaps my code is really breaking somewhere else

Comment: You can only use pages queries in top-level components (pages), if not, you should use a static query. Is `Map` a page?

Comment: It's a component. Should it be a page?

Comment: It's up to you, but if it's a page you will not able to use page queries. I've adapted it to your current needs (component) to use the proper query (static query)

Comment: It's working!!! Thanks so much :) Waiting for your website to come online :P Hopefully you'll have a blog to learn some more Gatsby!